# Can't get this media query working with boostrap 3 styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I want to change the width of a div\grid via a media query for desktop users, but can't get the style to apply.

Here is the div in Chrome dev tools:
[image]

So I want to set the width of my .ticketInforHeader div. I tried to do this, but it does not do anything:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .ticketInfoHeader {
        width 30%;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a colon (`:`) missing between `width` and `30%` in your snippet. Is that just a typo here, or is that a typo in your actual code? If the latter, you'll need to fix that before you uncover any other issues.

Comment: hahahah now I feel dumb. Yes, it seems that was the issue. Same code sans that typo works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .ticketInfoHeader {
        width 30% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Event with !important it doesn't do anything. Also, aren't I supposed to avoid !important whenever possible?

Comment: Yes you should avoid !important, but here you need to override bootstrap css style for .col-md-4 thus I gave a trivial answer, sad not working. Can you share some more HTML and css?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you're using Bootstrap's grid the width of the columns will be defined by the already existing classes like `.col-md-4`

You might need to add an `!important` to overwrite the Bootstrap style

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .ticketInfoHeader.col-md-4 {
    width 30% !important;
  }
}
```

but that doesn't look really good in the code and I feel it breaks the logic of using bootstrap's grid.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because even with  .ticketInfoHeader.col-md-4 and !important the style does not apply.